# Multipage error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: vba, excel

So I've probably spent the last week researching/trying to fix this annoying error but to no avail. Here's what I'm trying to do and the error I'm getting:

I have a userform that contains 12 multipage pages and to access each one I have coded previous/next buttons. Now, One of these pages is disabled through properties to hide from the user, that is until a specific checkbox is clicked. When it's clicked, the page is enabled, and the user is now able to view this page as well as all the others. when the checkbox is clicked again (making it false and no longer true), the page hides from the user's sight. This is basically what I'm trying to accomplish. The pages are like so:

page1, page2, page3, page4, *"page5"*, page6, etc.

As you can see, page5 is what is being disabled/enabled. Now also, something important to note, I've made the userform to appear before the workbook is actually visible using this:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False
    OpeningWindow.Show
    Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = True
    Application.Visible = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This I would like to avoid changing because it's vital that the userform appear first before the workbook because the workbook is acting as the storage/database for everything that is being typed in the userform using this multipage system. Now when I run the userform through VBA and test out this function "checkbox_click Enables/Disables multipage page", it works no problem. When I attempt to open it (as if you were starting up excel without anything opened) everything works fine, until I click the checkbox in question to enable the multipage to make it visible. This is where I'm getting the error "The object invoked has disconnected from it's clients". Now I've tried some other things out to see if I could get the same result:

1. Made the multipage page visible = False instead of Enabled = false.

Result: This somewhat works, however when attempting to click the previous button to go back a page (Page6 to Page5) when Page5 is visible = False, The previous button doesn't respond, as if it knows that Page5 is there even though it's invisible.

Anyway, to wrap things up, I would like to ask the community here if anyone knows exactly why, from the code I've provided below that is responsible for this "page enable/disable feature", I'm getting this object invoked has disconnected error and if there's a way to fix it.

```
Private Sub CheckBox119_Click()
    If CheckBox119.Value = True Then
        Me.MultiPage1.Pages(5).Enabled = True
        CheckBox138.Value = True
        Label309.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.MultiPage1.Pages(5).Enabled = False
        CheckBox138.Value = False
        Label309.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

CheckBox138 btw is located on Page5 and is there if the user wishes to click it to disable page5 and Jump to Page4, which is this code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox138_Click()
    If CheckBox138.Value = False Then
        MultiPage1.Value = 4
        CheckBox119.Value = False
        Label309.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, I'm relatively new to coding in VBA, but I'm always ready to learn.

Comment: Exactly which line throws the error?

Comment: It doesn't show it. When I launch the excel file (which is when the userform pops up before the workbook is visible) and attempt to click the checkbox, it gives the error and excel crashes. I wish I could re-create it in VBA to see which line throws it, but as I mentioned it works perfectly fine when ran in VBA.

Comment: Also, I seem to have found a workaround instead of using the method I'm trying to accomplish (which if anyone wants to know, I'll post an answer to show the code). However, I would still like to still figure this problem out in case issues like this occur in the future.

Comment: Could You provide some more info about what this multipage do? I' ve copied to excel your code and make siple two card multicard and it works fine - both on workbook open and when it is visible. So I think that the problem is caused by some other part of code.
Futhermore, you can add On Error GoTo ErrHandl and in ErrHandl You can write the error description to the cell in active sheet (keep public long and increase it at each error and use it as variable for row to write) using Cstr(Err.Discription). Maybe it will help to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Moreover, sometimes this error occurs when You migrate Your e.g. 2003 xls to new xlsm. So to exclude this I would first of all create new workbook and copy all modules, user forms, etc. and test it. Then I would copy worksheets to it and once again test.
But I think that that the error handler from above might help to figure out the problematic code.
In order to execute code to the end in Your ErrHandl: You should put at the bottom Err.Clear and Resume Next.

Comment: @Mikisz
Well the multipage contains up to 11 pages, each having their own use. There's two buttons, a previous and a next button, that allows the user to scroll between pages. When the excel file is launched, only the userform pops up (the workbook is hidden) and the page in question is disabled. Now I've set the multipage to show no tabs or buttons so the user doesn't see the pages, and the page before the disabled page contains a checkbox that, when clicked, enables the next page. I'll add the errorhandler to see if I can find more info about this.

Comment: hmmm interesting. @Mikisz, I followed your advice and placed an errhandlr into the checkbox_click code. It popped up as normal and gave the error number 0. Now even though that popped up, I was able to close the error pop up and then, for some reason, its as if the code I placed in the OP ran anyway. Now of course everytime I click the checkbox the error still pops up though. Also, nothing was highlighted in VBA.

Comment: I might have found the problem. Give me a few mintues to check something.

Comment: Yep I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around, I believe I figured out what the problem was. The checkbox138 in the disabled page was the culprit. By deleting the code Private sub checkbox138_click(), it works now. I'm not entirely sure why this is the case (so someone with more knowledge may be able to explain) But  When checkbox119 is clicked, checkbox138 is suppose to turn true being that's what the initial code expressed. However, even though making checkbox119 true is suppose to enable the disabled page followed by making checkbox138 true, there seems to be a hiccup. It seems checkbox138 is thinking the disabled page is still disabled (even though checkbox119 is suppose to enable it) therefore making the checkbox138 hidden.